# Relation between ConcurrentModificationException and

Tags: java, list, exception, arraylist, collections

I have created this list

```
List<Integer> first_solution = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and i have a previous list `randomPath` which is not empty

My goal is to copy a part from `randomPath` into the new list `first_solution`

This is a part of my code

```
i = 2;

if (distanceTraveled > tMax && !alreadyExecuted) {
            first_solution = randomPath.subList(0, i);
            displayPath(first_solution);
            alreadyExecuted = true;
    }
```

this code works without any problem perhaps when i use `first_solution` out of this function , i get this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

For example if i want to write

```
displayPath(first_solution);
```

out of `if {}`, i get that exception.

Comment: You haven't posted enough information. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61968631/edit) your question to post the full code or at least [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As the exception says, you're trying to modify a collection (probably a list) while looping over it. Either use an Iterator, or collect the items you want to delete in a separate list, then delete them all at once after looping.